# Jade Container checking Main connection

Tags: java, android, containers, agents-jade

I did this simple code of a remote container on android device and it works perfectly in general.

But when I type a wrong IP address of the main container it tries to connect (for minutes) and the method `OnFailure` doesn't execute at all.

I really need to make it stop trying to connect after few seconds.

```
 final Properties profile = new Properties();
 profile.setProperty(Profile.MAIN_HOST,MainIp);
 profile.setProperty(Profile.MAIN_PORT, "1099");
 profile.setProperty(Profile.JVM, Profile.ANDROID);

 runtimeServiceBinder.startAgentContainer(profile,  new RuntimeCallback<Void>(){
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fail !! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void arg0) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Done !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
    }
 });
```

Comment: How can I create the agent and add them dynamically to the main-container? I can add agent dynamically but per agent it creates a new container. But I want to create all of them in one container.